# cardano-cli: QueryEncoderUnsupportedQuery Query GetSystemStart TopLevelQueryDisabled

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

```
cardano-cli --version
cardano-cli 1.27.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev d870347b48c8ba0a81566876153eff23fce3ec64

cardano-cli query tip --mainnet
cardano-cli: QueryEncoderUnsupportedQuery Query GetSystemStart TopLevelQueryDisabled
```

I'm trying to get the current tip(slot) for my my transaction ttl.

eidt:

```
cardano-cli query tip --shelley-mode --mainnet
Command failed: query tip  Error: Unsupported mode: ShelleyMode
```

after i added --shelley-mode flag, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try running the query with `--shelley-mode` flag?

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the [release version](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases/latest), which - for 1.27.0 (current mainnet) - is `8fe46140a52810b6ca456be01d652ca08fe730bf`.

Using commits later than current stable release should *only* be done if you're sure if a specific commit is compatible and works - and should be done on testnet instead